# Datasheet part dimensions

Tags: datasheet, dimensions

I'm trying to draw up a part in EAGLE, but am having a hard time making out the datasheet dimensions:

[image]

For example, with the pin width, it's not clear whether it's 0.51 (mm, I presume) or 0.31. Likewise with width, is it 4.00 or 3.80?

This is a SOIC package, although I understand they vary from one to another. As a side question: what dimensions would be suitable for the pads?

DATASHEET: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm4140.pdf

Comment: Post the datasheet. There is an explanation of the notation used.

Comment: Those are ranges of possible variation.  But this looks like a fairly normal SOIC-8 you can probably find an existing footprint for it - at the least you should consult some to inform the pad width question.

Comment: I'm using the element14 TI library. Can you think of a part with the same footprint I could use?

Comment: Rather than looking for a donor part, look directly for the footprint. 
 Click over to the footprints tab in likely suspect libraries.  Or you can use `grep` on the library files themselves.

Comment: The first number is in inches, and the number in parentheses is millimeters. As Chris Stratton says, this is a normal 8 pin SOIC.

Comment: There are many SOIC-8 options. How do I go about finding one with the same dimensions? It's hard to measure them when opening each footprint.

Comment: Properly designed footprints are usually having enough tolerance to accommodate any corresponding package with their possible variance.

Answer (score 3):

As indicated on the drawing, the first number is inches and the number in parentheses is millimeters. When two values are given they are the minimum and maximum dimensions.

The part itself appears to be a pretty standard SOIC package, but TI recommends a very non-standard PCB footprint for best results. This layout is provided and discussed in the datasheet.

As always, you should make sure you have a good layout by printing the copper layers at 1X scale on paper, then placing the actual components where they are supposed to go. Really, do it.

Comment: I stopped doing the paper test thanks to accurate 3D models of component packages. You can accomplish the same thing in CAD now with more precise visualization of how the leads line up with the pads than you'd ever get squinting at a piece of paper that has the part roughly placed in the correct location.

Comment: From what I can understand, the datasheet suggests "isolating" the device by means of a u shaped slot (is this etched, or actually milled into the PCB?), but the footprint of the device itself is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the answer is right below the diagram you snipped:

[image]

See Note A.  That clearly explains the two numbers with the second in parenthesis.

Different numbers above and below a line are a common convention for showing the maximum and minimum values.  For example, it is saying that the pin width can vary from 12 to 20 mils, or 0.31 to 0.51 mm.

I do think that it's wrong in this context to use a common as the decimal point for the mm values.  The rest of the datasheet is in English, so it is inconsistent that this one part is not in English.  Still, the meaning is clear enough.